# how to add padding after text and variable in python string format

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to add space after I write text and my variable in Python Format String. So I want to align and add 50 spaces such as the below picture.

Here is what I want to do:
[image]

I wrote this code but it does not work

```
print("{:<50s}{}".format("Enter the point ID of unknown point ",i,)," :",end=" ")
```

Comment: use pprint
https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html

Answer (score 1):

You have to first format your prompt, and in a second step print this prompt:

```
prompt = f"Enter the point ID of unknown point {i}"
print(f"{prompt:<50s} : ", end="")
```

or count, how many places are left for the number:

```
print(f"Enter the point ID of unknown point {i:<14d} : ", end="")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use f-string literal to solve this

```
Spaces = ' ' * 50
print(f"Enter the point ID of unknown point : {i}{Spaces}")
```

Use `{Spaces}` wherever you want to add 50 spaces